# Error creating database in SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am getting an error when trying to save data in SQLite database. My application has two EditText fields, when user taps 'save' the data entered have to be saved in database.

I am using android studio 3.0.1. Bellow is the error I am getting:

```
16:13:01.270 12710-12710/com.vysh.gridlayoutmanagerrecyclerview 
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: myTable
02-03 16:13:01.277 12710-12710/com.vysh.gridlayoutmanagerrecyclerview 
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Password=123 Name=luane

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: myTable (code 
1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO myTable(Password,Name) VALUES (?,?)

at 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native 
Method)
```

When user taps 'save' button, the method insertData() is called. Bellow is the class which contains this method:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

class MyDbAdapter {
    MyDbHelper helper;

    public MyDbAdapter(Context context)
    {
        helper = new MyDbHelper(context);
    }

public long insertData(String name, String password)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MyDbHelper.NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(MyDbHelper.PASSWORD, password);
    long id = db.insert(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null , contentValues);
    //Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return id;
}

static class MyDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "myTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_Version = 1;
    private static final String UID="_id";
    private static final String NAME = "Name";
    private static final String PASSWORD= "Password";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME +
            "( "+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +NAME+ "VARCHAR(225)" + PASSWORD+"VARCHAR(225));";
    // private static final String DROP_TABLE ="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
    private Context context;

    public MyDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_Version);
        this.context=context;
        Message.message(context,"Started...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {

            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            Message.message(context,"TABLE CREATED");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Message.message(context,""+e);
        }
      }
    }// end of MyDbHelper
}
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: clearly says table name `myTable` doesn't exist. Also remove the try catch inside `onCreate`

Comment: why is better not use try catch in onCreate method?

Comment: It's a simple query for creating the table. You have to be aware atleast about the reason why your table is not created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have omitted spaces between column names and the column types. This will result in the table not being created due to the syntax error (a column name cannot contain **`(`**)).

The reason why this is not detected until you click the save button is that the database will not be created/opened until either `getReabableDatabase` or `getWriteableDatabase` is called.

You should change :-

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME +
            "( "+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +NAME+ "VARCHAR(225)" + PASSWORD+"VARCHAR(225));";
```

To be something like :-

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME +
            "( "+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +NAME+ " VARCHAR(225)" + PASSWORD+" VARCHAR(225));";
```

Note that you will need to delete the App's data or uninstall the App after making the changes, so that the database is deleted and thus allowing the `onCreate` method to be run.

Comment: I guess so. The worst nightmare comes when we keep using try catch being not sure.

Comment: Solved! thank you! I forgot to use spaces and also comma. Here is the expression:    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME +
                "( "+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +NAME+ " VARCHAR(225) ," + PASSWORD+" VARCHAR(225));";